# How to calculate the autocorrelation of Ornstein Uhlenbeck process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let us consider the following SDE:
$$
d x(t)=-\alpha \cdot(x(t)-\mu) \cdot d t+\sqrt{2 \cdot \alpha} \cdot \sigma \cdot d W(t)
$$
Its solution is a stationary stochastic process called the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. How could I calculate the autocorrelation of the Ornstein Uhlenbeck process?

**My attempt.**
Thanks to @Chaos comment, I deleted the previous wrong attempt and I tried to solve the equation following [analytic solution to Ornstein-Uhlenbeck SDE](https://planetmath.org/analyticsolutiontoornsteinuhlenbecksde). In doing so, I obtained the equation:
$$x(t)=\mu+e^{\alpha(s-t)}\left(x(s)-\mu\right)+\sqrt{2\alpha}\sigma e^{-\alpha t}\int_s^t e^{\alpha u}dW(u)$$
The autocorrelation is:
$$\mathrm{R}_{x}(\tau)=\mathrm{E}\left[\mathrm{x}(t) \mathrm{x}^{*}(t+\tau)\right]$$
But... how can I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried something? Please add that in the OP

Comment: @Snoop, yes, I added my attempt. Thank you

Comment: assume that $\alpha$ and $\sigma$ are constants, then the two Itô integrals would equal $\sqrt{2\alpha}\sigma W_t$ and $\sqrt{2\alpha}\sigma W_{t+\tau}$ respectively. Those are not independent and thus you cannot split the expectation and set it equal to $0$.

Comment: by the way, the O.U. equation can be solved explicitly, you should start by doing that

Comment: @Chaos, thank you! I tried to follow your suggestion, but I stopped at the computation of autocorrelation